# DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE automatically decrease size after shutdown

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-11g

I am using oracle database 11gR2.

I increased db_recovery_file_dest size with alter command

```
alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size=60G scope=both;
```

When I shutdown database and again open database then db_recovery_file_dest_size automatically changed to default size 10G.

Now I am getting error

```
the database is not available due to the following conditions stuck archiver
```

How to solve this error

Comment: Which edition are you on?

Comment: @Michael Kutz what does mean which edition?

Comment: Post result of `select * from v$version`

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.1.0 Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal. If you set a parameter without specifying `sid`, then it will create/modify the entry in spfile with `sid=*`. But if you have another value set with the actual `sid` (instance name), that takes precedence over `*`, and the value remains unchanged.

Demonstration:

```
SQL> show parameter db_reco

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest                string      /fra
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 20G

SQL> show spparameter db_recovery_file_dest_size

SID      NAME                          TYPE        VALUE
-------- ----------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------
*        db_recovery_file_dest_size    big integer 20G

SQL> alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size =10G sid='MIN19' scope=spfile;

System altered.

SQL> show spparameter db_recovery_file_dest_size

SID      NAME                          TYPE        VALUE
-------- ----------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------
MIN19    db_recovery_file_dest_size    big integer 10G
*        db_recovery_file_dest_size    big integer 20G
```

My instance is called `MIN19`, so even though 20G is set for `*`, it will start with 10G:

```
SQL> startup force nomount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  536868920 bytes
Fixed Size                  8898616 bytes
Variable Size             339738624 bytes
Database Buffers          180355072 bytes
Redo Buffers                7876608 bytes

SQL> show parameter db_recovery_file_dest_size

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 10G
SQL> show spparameter db_recovery_file_dest_size

SID      NAME                          TYPE        VALUE
-------- ----------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------
MIN19    db_recovery_file_dest_size    big integer 10G
*        db_recovery_file_dest_size    big integer 20G
```

I may change it to whatever I want, it will not have effect:

```
SQL> alter system set db_recovery_file_dest_size = 30G scope=spfile;

System altered.

SQL> show spparameter db_recovery_file_dest_size

SID      NAME                          TYPE        VALUE
-------- ----------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------
MIN19    db_recovery_file_dest_size    big integer 10G
*        db_recovery_file_dest_size    big integer 30G
SQL> startup force nomount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  536868920 bytes
Fixed Size                  8898616 bytes
Variable Size             339738624 bytes
Database Buffers          180355072 bytes
Redo Buffers                7876608 bytes
SQL> show parameter db_recovery_file_dest_size

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 10G
```

Make sure to clean up overlapping parameters and use only 1 of them to avoid confusion. Example:

```
SQL> alter system reset db_recovery_file_dest_size sid = 'MIN19';

System altered.

SQL> show spparameter db_recovery_file_dest_size

SID      NAME                          TYPE        VALUE
-------- ----------------------------- ----------- ----------------------------
*        db_recovery_file_dest_size    big integer 30G
SQL> startup force nomount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area  536868920 bytes
Fixed Size                  8898616 bytes
Variable Size             339738624 bytes
Database Buffers          180355072 bytes
Redo Buffers                7876608 bytes
SQL> show parameter db_recovery_file_dest_size

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
db_recovery_file_dest_size           big integer 30G
SQL>
```